# Joining two tables, sorting and finding the Top revenue values

Tags: sql, join, sql-order-by

I am trying to create a query with the top 3 shops that have the highest average revenue amount and retail_type being fashion and shoes. I have to join 3 tables where I have to join 2 to the 1st one. Something seems to be wrong with the syntax below:

```
Select * from (Select
  a.shop_id,
  c.retail_type,
  avg(b.revenue_amount) as avg_revenue_amount
From
  shops a
  Left join rev b on a.shop_id = b.shop_id
  Left join trans c on b.trans_id = c.trans_id
Where
  c.retail_type in (‘fashion’, ‘ shoes ’)
Group by
  1,
  2
Order by
  avg_revenue_amount desc)
limit 10;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Hi, I haven't been asked to use a specific database, but just write a sql code (generic?) I use a sql validator online. And all I get is that my syntax is invalid, without providing me with a specific error.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: "Something seems to be wrong" is not helpful. PS You/we can expect your error to be a faq.  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS DBMS matters. Say whatever you can about  the website & SQL syntax you are to use per the reference material you were given. Don't just say you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra bracket on the line:

> avg_revenue_amount) desc)

Also you have typo on the second line: `a.shop.id` -> `a.shop_id` and another problem with quotes: `‘fashion’, ‘ shoes ’` -> `'fashion', 'shoes'`

Check edited query on the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb164/10/0).

Comment: Thanks, I removed the bracket and ran it through the SQL validator and it still shows me that the syntax is invalid

Comment: Also You have typo on the second line: `a.shop.id` -> `a.shop_id`

Comment: Just checked, that's also not it

Comment: What's the error? Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb164/10/0 - query executes without errors

Comment: And another problem with quotes: `‘fashion’, ‘ shoes ’` -> `'fashion', 'shoes'`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
select s.shop_id, t.retail_type,
       avg(r.revenue_amount) as avg_revenue_amount
from shops s join
      rev r
      on s.shop_id = r.shop_id join
      trans 
      t
      on r.trans_id = t.trans_id
where t.retail_type in ('fashion', 'shoes')
group by s.shop_id, t.retail_type
order by avg_revenue_amount desc
limit 10;
```

You don't specify your database, but the following are potentially problematic:

- Bad quotes in the `in` clause.
- Lack of alias after the derived table.
- Use of numeric placeholders in `GROUP BY`.

Not all of these are necessarily errors, but they could be depending on your database.

The following would not cause a syntax error but might cause other problems:

- Spaces around a string for an `IN` comparison means the comparison might not work.
- Use of arbitrary letters for table aliases makes the query really hard to follow.
- The `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN`s to inner joins so `LEFT JOIN`s are highly misleading.
- The subquery is superfluous.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and runs in the SQL syntax check I am using.